# Apply CSS to elements that do not match the data attribute

Tags: jquery, css, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to create a sort of filter.

When a user clicks a button, it will grab the ID of that button, and apply `display:none;` to all elements that do not match the `data` attribute given.

HTML:

```
<div class="job-list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid half">
            <div class="job-item" data-job-type="fulltime">
                <h3>Marketing &amp; Communications Manager</h3>
                <h4>Central London -  salary competitive</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

       <div class="grid half">
           <div class="job-item" data-job-type="parttime">
               <h3>Senior PR &amp; Media Manager</h3>
               <h4>Central London -  salary dependent on experience</h4>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

When the user clicks on a button, the var `selection` is set as either `parttime` or `fulltime`

```
var selection = 'fulltime';
```

I am then trying to match elements on the page that are:

a) within `.job-list`

b) have `data-job-type="[the selection var set above]"`

```
$('.job-list div[data-job-type!="'+selection+'"]').css('display','none');
```

However what I find is that it selects the entire of `.job-list` and applies `display:none;` to that, rather than the sub-elements that match?

### JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h9s3szg2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [**documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

> Select elements that **either don't** have the specified attribute, or do have the specified attribute but not with a certain value.

Your selector is over aggressive. It is selecting all divs even if they do not have the attribute because they fullfill the condition `[data-job-type!="'+selection+'"]`. Add an extra `[data-job-type]` to the selector to target only divs with that attribute

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    var selection = 'fulltime';
    $('.job-list div[data-job-type][data-job-type!="' + selection + '"]').closest('.grid').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.job-item {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Click me!</div>
<div class="job-list">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="grid half">
      <div class="job-item" data-job-type="fulltime">
        <h3>Marketing &amp; Communications Manager</h3>

        <h4>Central London -  salary competitive</h4>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid half">
      <div class="job-item" data-job-type="parttime">
        <h3>Senior PR &amp; Media Manager</h3>

        <h4>Central London -  salary dependent on experience</h4>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some side notes.

1. `hide()` can be used in place of `css('display', 'none')`
2. It is better to `hide()` the overall sub container, in this case, `grid`

Comment: upvoted but i guess the `.grid` container `div` should be hidden instead, but depending if any styling is applied to it: `$('.job-list .grid:has(div[data-job-type][data-job-type!="' + selection + '"])')`

Comment: @A.Wolff, absolutely. Thanks for your useful insight. Updated my answer